# proper smarty installation centos

Tags: centos, installation

I want to properly install smarty on my VPS I have plesk and I'm not sure if I need to doe this in plesk or from command line or ftp

the simple instructions says to

```
$> cd YOUR_DOWNLOAD_DIR
$> gtar -zxvf Smarty-3.0.tar.gz
$> mkdir /usr/local/lib/php/Smarty
$> cp -r Smarty-3.0/libs/* /usr/local/lib/php/Smarty
```

however this /usr/local/lib/php/ directory doesn't exist
so I'm not sure where to put it and if there is a better way of installing via plesk ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure the where default include paths are on Centos, rather then me looking it up for you, let me tell you one simple way you can figure this out.

Simply setup a standard phpinfo script, and go look at the output.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

The important detail to find will be in the **core** section, and you are looking for the item labeled `include_path`.  Any PHP file in this list of directories will be able to loaded without explicitly using the full path.

With that in mind you have some options:

- You could copy the Smarty files in one of these folders.
- You could symlink Smarty into one of these folders from the `/usr/local/lib/php` location, if you want to keep the stuff installed by packages and stuff you installed from source separate (PROTIP, this is a good thing)
- You could simply update the php configuration and add your new `/usr/local/lib/php` path into the `include_path`

Comment: right now it jsut show .: which seem off to me ?

Comment: Maybe CentOS doesn't setup any default include PATH, I am not a regular CentOS user, so I don't know.  Just go find your PHP.ini and see what is configured, then fix it.